# Are there certain foods that harms the throat in the long run?

Tags: voice, health

Are there any food/drinks that, if consumed regularly over a long period of time, would have a *permanent* negative effect on the throat, and especially the singing voice?

Comment: Broken glass...

Comment: @NReilingh, You mean fishbone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Permanently? Not really; there's nothing that would be generally called "food" or "drink" that would immediately and permanently have a detrimental effect on your singing voice.

However, avoid cigarette smoking (really any type of smoking or tobacco use) and alcohol, as these can have a cumulative effect that builds up over time. If you stop now, before any change becomes noticeable, your body will heal. However, once the effects of these things reaches a critical mass, they will become permanent, and while they may improve, your career as a singer will likely be over.

I would also caution against regularly eating very spicy foods. The capsaicin will actually irritate and erode the mucous membranes of the mouth and throat, which in the extreme can cause permanent damage. They can also cause acid reflux which can damage the pharynx in other ways. I don't mean cut out spicy food entirely; I love jalapenos and chili and you probably couldn't get me to stop eating them entirely. Just cut back on the heat, and don't eat these things every day.

Comment: i know acid reflux is painful. but is acid reflux that dangerous?

Comment: @Pacerier: Absolutely. Over time, stomach acid wears away your esophagus lining, which greatly increases the risk of throat cancer.
And KeithS, out of curiosity, do you have any references to the spicy foods stuff?  I'm not trying to call you out, I'm just interested in it.

Comment: Anything bad about coffee? also, alcohol?

Comment: @Keiths, How would regular consumption of alcohol damage the throat?

Comment: @Pacerier [throat cancer](http://www.cancer.gov/cancertopics/factsheet/Risk/alcohol) can put a [real](http://www.dnaindia.com/entertainment/report-legendary-pakistani-singer-reshma-passes-away-after-long-battle-with-throat-cancer-1913138) [crimp](http://www.hulldailymail.co.uk/Joe-Longthorne-battling-throat-cancer/story-21120331-detail/story.html) [in your vocal style](http://www.ranker.com/list/famous-people-who-died-of-throat-cancer/reference).

Comment: Would moderate or light drinking hurt the throat? Should singers avoid alcohol altogether?

Comment: I would say that light to moderate alcohol consumption during times not related to singing is harmless, and some say it can even be beneficial; however, taken just before singing, or in heavy doses, it will cause damage that is compounded by trying to sing through it.

Comment: Can you provide a link that validates your claim that spicy food "can cause permanent damage"?   This seems unknown to medical science from my superficial search just now, and my personal experience is that spicy chilli is extremely helpful for me - it is the only way I can clear my thick mucus (no drinking 10+ glasses of water a day and humidifying doesn't get me there)  and has become indispensable for my best tone.  (fortunately i love spicy food!)